# Comma Usage (Basic)

Tags: commas, writing-style

> "I adapted to these situations and took myself in a new direction
>   closer to home at a community college. "

Or

> "I adapted to these situations and took myself in a new direction,
>   closer to home, at a community college. "

Not too sure which version is correct. If I had to guess I would think the second version. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think one of those is wrong?

Comment: The first example seems like there should be a slight pause between "direction" and "closer" but Im not sure if it needs a comma to be grammatically correct

Comment: Well i think the first is grammatically right for sure,however,the second version is also reasonable for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I adapted to these situations and took myself in a new direction closer to home at a community college.

Whether you punctuate this sentence beyond the period/full stop depends on 1) how you wish to define the semantic relationship between *direction* and *closer to home at a community college* and perhaps between the latter two phrases, and 2) whether you want to lay particular stress on *direction*, *home*, or *community college*. These are more rhetorical than grammatical concerns.

No comma anywhere is the equivalent of:

> I adapted to these situations and took myself in a new direction that was closer to home at a community college.

You took yourself in this particular new direction rather than some other new direction you might have chosen. Your hesitance with this option suggests that this isn't quite what you had in mind.

If you wish to qualify that direction rather than restrict it, i.e., let the two subsequent phrases become supplemental information and make the *new direction* alone more important, you could write:

> I adapted to these situations and took myself in a new direction, closer to home at a community college.

If you wish to stress *new direction* even further:

> I adapted to these situations and took myself in a new direction: closer to home at a community college.

Another option is to set off *closer to home* with commas:

> I adapted to these situations and took myself in a new direction, closer to home, at a community college.

This is the equivalent of:

> I adapted to these situations and took myself in a new direction, which was closer to home, at a community college.

You have the choice of accentuating *community college* even further:

> I adapted to these situations and took myself in a new direction closer to home: at a community college.

None of these options change the meaning very much, but they do change which part of the sentence carries more importance.

While we're at it, I'd probably change the first clause into a participle:

> Adapting to these situations, I took myself...

Answer (score 0):

You said in a comment:

> seems like there should be a slight pause between "direction" and
>   "closer" but Im not sure if it needs a comma to be grammatically
>   correct

The function of punctuation marks is not to instruct readers how to phrase the text as they read; it is to clarify the text's meaning, which is achieved by marking the logical divisions within it. If you do that correctly readers will figure out how to phrase it while reading. The two should end up similar but writers should be thinking about the latter.
It is not wrong to place commas on both sides of 'closer to home'. That turns those words into a parenthetic aside, a detour from the main body of the sentence to provide an additional piece of unessential information.
I would not bother with commas there, or more precisely, I would not bother *my readers* with commas there, in almost all situations. Perhaps, but it's still unlikely, if those words were dialogue in fiction. Doing that would tell readers the character phrased what they said in a rather odd manner.